# How to crop some part of a view as separate view

Tags: android, imageview, android-view, fresco

I have a SimpleDraweeView (from Fresco) like Imageview in my android app. Its dimensions are match_parent for both height and width. I want to create a separate view which will be showing the bottom 54dp of content of the SimpleDraweeView . 
The new view will have width as screen width (match_parent) and height as 54dp .

How can i extract the bottom 54dp height of the SimpleDraweeView and whatever image portion comes in that , create a separate view which will show that 54dp height content.

So there should be method which takes SimpleDraweeView as param and should output View/ImageView with the required image content.

Answer (score 0):

Use ConstraintLayout, and set the view2's layout as:

```
constraint_bottom_tobottomof=@+id/view1
```

and height is 54dp, then it occupies the bottom 54dp of view1.